Problema al mezclar Stack.Screen con Elementos que incluyan Scroll (Flatlist, ScrollView)
Estoy desarrollando una pantalla de Chat en React Native, pero tengo un problema cuando uso
Stack.Screen junto con elementos como Flatlist o ScrollView.
Mi código es el siguiente:
import { Stack, useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { FlatList, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { dataChats, images } from '../../../data';
import { CheckChatIcon, DeleteIcon, DoubleCheckChatIcon, OptionsVerticalIcon, PinIcon, SendIcon, VoiceRecorderIcon } from '../../../assets/icons/icons';
import {
    Menu,
    PaperProvider,
} from 'react-native-paper';
import { formatTimestamp } from '../../../utils/utils';
import ScreenLayout from '../../../components/screen-layout/ScreenLayout';


const iconStatusMessage = (status) => {
    const icons = {
        SEEN: <DoubleCheckChatIcon color="#35E3AF" size={14} />,
        SENT: <CheckChatIcon color="#7B7B7B" size={14} />,
        DELIVERED: <DoubleCheckChatIcon color="#7B7B7B" size={14} />,
    }
    return icons[status]
}

export default function Chat() {
    const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
    console.log(id);

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const openMenu = () => setVisible(true);
    const closeMenu = () => setVisible(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const flRef = useRef();

    const messages = dataChats[id]?.messages || [];


    return (
        <ScreenLayout withHeader>
            <PaperProvider>
                <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        headerTitle: "Message",
                        headerTintColor: "black",
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                        },
                        headerShadowVisible: false,
                        headerBackTitle: '',
                    }}
                />
                <View className="rounded-lg bg-green-p-50 p-4">
                    <View className="flex-row justify-between">
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-4">
                            <Image source={{ uri: images[0].src }} style={{ width: 52, height: 52, borderRadius: 15, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />
                            <Text className="font-semibold text-lg">John Doe</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-4">
                            <Text className="font-normal text-xs">12/09/2024</Text>
                            <View>
                                <Menu
                                    contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white", position: 'relative', top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0, width: 120 }}
                                    visible={visible}
                                    onDismiss={closeMenu}
                                    anchor={<TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu}>
                                        <OptionsVerticalIcon size={16} />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>}>
                                    <Menu.Item onPress={() => { }} title="Pin" leadingIcon={() => <PinIcon size={22} />} />
                                    <Menu.Item onPress={() => { }} title="Delete" leadingIcon={() => <DeleteIcon />} />
                                </Menu>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <Text className="font-semibold text-sm mt-3">About the publish: <Text className="font-normal text-sm">Publish little</Text></Text>
                </View>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}
                    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 90 : 0}
                >
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <FlatList
                            ref={flRef}
                            data={messages}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.content}-${index}`}
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <View className={`flex-row w-full ${item.me ? "justify-end" : ""}`}>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text className="text-gray-500 text-xs text-right">{formatTimestamp(item.timestamp)}</Text>
                                        <View className="flex-row items-center">
                                            <View
                                                className={`py-2 px-3 rounded-lg ${item.me ? "bg-green-primary" : "bg-white"}`}
                                            >
                                                {item.reaction && (
                                                    <View className="bg-white rounded-full w-6 h-6 items-center justify-center absolute z-50" style={styles.reaction}>
                                                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{item.reaction}</Text>
                                                    </View>
                                                )}
                                                <Text className="text-black text-lg">{item.content}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-1 justify-end mt-1">
                                            <Text className="text-gray-500 text-xs text-right capitalize">{item?.status}</Text>
                                            {iconStatusMessage(item?.status)}
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )}
                            contentContainerStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
                        />
                        <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-2 mb-6 mt-2">
                            <TextInput
                                className={"text-black bg-white rounded-md px-5 py-3 flex-1"}
                                placeholder="Escribe un mensaje..."
                                placeholderTextColor="#9E9E9E"
                                keyboardAppearance="dark"
                                onChangeText={setText}
                                value={text}
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { }}>
                                <View className="bg-green-p-50 rounded-md p-2 w-10 h-10 items-center justify-center border border-green-primary" >
                                    {text.length > 0 ? <SendIcon size={20} /> : <VoiceRecorderIcon size={20} />}
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </PaperProvider>
        </ScreenLayout>
    )
}

Si comento el Stack.Screen todo funciona perfectamente, pero si se mantiene tengo errores de visualización que se verán de manera más clara en un video que dejaré seguidamente:



Cada vez que escribo en el input comienza a brincar y desaparecer como se muestra en las imágenes.
Dejo un video donde se muestra con mayor claridad.
Video de muestra
